# Converting string to floats; can't clear stringstream correctly?

Tags: c++, stringstream, c++98

Disclaimer: I must use c++ 98

As part of a class assignment, I have been tasked to convert space-delimited strings into floats (then calculate a span with those floats, but that is irrelevant to my problem). The strings are coming from text files. If there are any discrepancies with the float, I am supposed to ignore it and consider it corrupted. For example, a text file could consist of a line that looks like this:

```
34.6 24.2 18.a 54.3 20.0 15.6
```

In this case, 18.a would simply be considered corrupt and no further manipulation has to be done to it.

Now, I am having a problem clearing my stringstream of corrupt data. For reference, here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //Open file
    ifstream infile("dataFile");

    //Get all file input into a single string
    string line;
    string buffer;
    while (getline(infile, buffer)) {
        line += buffer + " ";
    }

    infile.close();

    //Populate vector
    float temp;

    //I have tried to clear the stream with `data >> dummy` for
    //both string and single char types below, but `data >> string`
    //always clears too much, and `data >> char` doesn't seem to clear
    //correctly either

    //string dummy;
    //char dummy;
    vector<float> temps;
    istringstream data(line);
    while (data) {
        //values between -100 and 100 are also considered corrupt
        if (data >> temp && (temp <= 100 && temp >= -100)) {
            temps.push_back(temp);
        }
        else if (!data.eof()) {
            data.clear();

            //trying to ignore all characters until I reach a space
            //but that doesn't work correctly either

            data.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ' ');
            //data >> dummy;
            //cout << "Dummy: " << dummy << endl;
            temps.push_back(-101.0);
        }
    }

    //display resulting vector values
    for(int i=0; i<temps.size(); ++i) {
        cout << temps[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

My issue lies within the `while (data)` loop, specifically, inside the `else if (!data.eof())` block. When `data >> temp (type float)` fails, the `else if` block runs. I clear the consequential `failbit` and attempt to ignore the remaining characters until the next space-delimiter comes up. However, a text file with a line like such:

```
a *a -100.1 100.1 a 10.a a 13-6s 12abc -12.a
```

produces problems. 13 and -6 are both processed as valid floats. I want to ignore the entire chunk of `13-6s`, because these values are intended to be space-delimited.

What is the correct way to deal with this `istringstream` issue, where the characters are not being ignored the way I want?

I have been told by my professor that I can accomplish this with very basic STL techniques. He explicitly recommended to use `stringstream` as a way to parse floats. Is he in the wrong here?

Please comment for further clarity, if needed; I've been at this for quite some time now and would much appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Comment: Another solution may be to read each space delimited entry into a string and use a regular expression to check if it is possible to cast to float. Just a note: It seems you've managed to reduce your problem to just a couple lines of code, it would be much easier to everyone if you reduced the actual code block to just the offending code. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you.

Comment: @JustinHellreich Thanks, advice taken. As for regex and casting, I don't think my professor would approve of such techniques for so early in the class, as he has not taught us those things yet.

Comment: are you sure your professor is so interested in error handling? maybe he meant that just reading space-separated list of floats is simple to do by `stringstream`? or maybe he didn't think about handling `13-6s` case?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. He gave us a sort of "test suite" with dozens of input files to test. Both lines come directly from the files we will be graded on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  std::string temp;

  // cin will write to temp with each space delimited entry
  while (std::cin >> temp) {
    std::stringstream s(temp);
    float f;

    // the first case checks if the actual write the float succeeds
    // the second case checks if the entire stringstream has been read
    if (!(s >> f) || !s.eof()) {
      std::cout << temp << " failed!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
      std::cout << f << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Apologies for not being able to answer your `stringstream` question but this solution should remove any necessity for that.

Note that input of `34.6 24.2 18.a 54.3 20.0 15.6` returns an output of:

```
34.6
24.2
18.a failed!
54.3
20
15.6
```

Edit: I added a case to the `if` statement to handle the stranger cases (i.e. 13-6s). It's a neat solution I found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13044/#msg62827).

Edit 2: I annotated some of the more complicated parts.

Comment: This code does not recognize such an input like 13-6 as invalid.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I added a condition to check if the entire `stringstream` has been read which should handle these edge cases.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for pointing that out. I added some comments, but I'll be happy to add more or change the formatting if there's a more standard way of doing this.

Comment: It's not obvious exactly which of the differences from the code in the question actually address the question.  Your code seems to need its input from stdin, which is quite different to the original code.  A really well structured answer will identify the problems in the question's code and describe what measures will fix it, before presenting a complete program as solution.

Comment: Well, I don't really think it's necessary to keep the same input/output structure as the question. The core goal of the question was to convert space delimited text to floats and that's what I addressed. And since my complete solution is really just a few lines compared to the actual question, I'm not sure why we can't let code 'speak' for itself in some cases.

Comment: This is so simple.. and it works. Although `std::stringstream ss("a *a -100.1 100.1 a 10.a a 13-6s 12abc -12.a")` and `while (ss >> temp)` fits my code better. Can someone explain why multiple layers of `stringstream` works but my solution doesn't? I'm really confused as to why my solution doesn't work.

Comment: The issue with your solution is actually the same mistake I originally made. `data >> temp` (in your first `if`) is going to split after it finds the longest possible float. So if `data` holds `13-6s`, `data >> temp` is going to set `temp` to 13. Notice that `data` is not actually empty (i.e. it is not EOF), which is why `!s.eof()` catches this case.

Comment: Also note that I didn't use `getline`. Using `cin` to write to a string will separate the input by spaces. Once you have the space delimited string, you can validate that it is a float using this logic: `(!(s >> f) || !s.eof())` which writes the string to a float and validates that the entire string was written.

Comment: Right, the `failbit` for `data` is set when it reaches the `-` in `13-6s`. But then I remove the `failbit` with `data.clear()` and I remove the conflicting `-6s` all the way to the space delimiter with `data.ignore()`. Then `data` should be right up to the next space delimited chunk, right? I'm trying to get a fundamental understanding of this as part of my class.

Comment: Also, I use `getline` only because the input files for grading have an arbitrary number of values on multiple given lines; `cin` isn't an option. But I end up with a valid space delimited string that way anyway. It is just the `failbit` and `data` issue that I have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135618/discussion-between-justin-hellreich-and-james-lemieux).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::string line( "a *a -100.1 100.1 -100 a 10.a a 13-6s 100 12abc -12.a" );
    std::istringstream is( line );

    std::vector<float> values;
    std::string item;

    while ( is >> item )
    {
        const char *s = item.c_str();
        char *tail;

        float value = std::strtof( s, &tail );

        if ( *tail == '\0' && -100.0f <= value && value <= 100.0f ) 
        {
            values.push_back( value );
        }           
    }


    for ( float value : values ) std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
-100 100
```

If to use this string

```
std::string line( "34.6 24.2 18.a 54.3 20.0 15.6" );
```

then the program output will be

```
34.6 24.2 54.3 20 15.6
```

Another approach is the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::string line( "a *a -100.1 100.1 -100 a 10.a a 13-6s 100 12abc -12.a" );
//  std::string line( "34.6 24.2 18.a 54.3 20.0 15.6" );
    std::istringstream is( line );

    std::vector<float> values;

    while ( !is.eof() )
    {
        float value;
        int c;

        if ( not ( is >> value ) || ( ( c = is.get() ) != ' ' && c != std::char_traits<char>::eof() ) )
        {
            is.clear();
            is.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ' );
        }
        else if ( -100.0f <= value && value <= 100.0f ) 
        {
            values.push_back( value );
        }           
    }

    for ( float value : values ) std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the same as shown above.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my post I must use c++ 98. I tagged the post but forgot to explicitly declare that. It is my understanding that `strtof` is new in c++ 11, right? I know of `atoi()`, but my professor urged me to use `stringstream` instead of `atoi()`.

Comment: @JamesLemieux See my updated post. The range based for loop can be substituted for an ordinary loop.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow @JustinHellreich Why exactly is my code not working? When the failbit is set for `data`, representing an invalid float, why can I not just clear the failbit, ignore the conflicting float, and move on?

Comment: @JamesLemieux This if statement if (data >> temp && (temp <= 100 && temp >= -100)) {
does not check whether there is invalid symbols after the read value. However it is added to the vector.

Comment: Does the `float temp; if (data >> temp ...) {` not do exactly that? I have tested the code and the problem is with the `failbit` and freeing up my `stringstream`, `data`. If someone can enlighten me as to why the `istream::ignore()` is not doing what I think it should, that would solve why my code does not work.